# Priority Queue documentation confusion

Tags: python, dictionary, priority-queue

I'm well-aware Python has a documentation for Priority Queues, as can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes). My confusion lies in how they use their "entry_finder". It seems to me that they imply that entry_finder is a dictionary of references to entries in the queues, which allows them to modify entries in the queue.

My question is, why does this behave this way?

For example, if I were to do something like

```
x = 3

entry_finder = [x]

arr = [ ]

arr.append(x)

entry_finder[0] = -1
```

Then the entry in arr would still read 3. Why does Python suddenly treat entry_finder as a dictionary of references rather than copying the entries in the documentation? Is it because we are using heappush as opposed to appending?

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: No. Python **always behaves this way**. See the linked by user2357112. Assignment *never copies*. Other than that, you are simply modifying two different *lists*.

Comment: Ooh, thank you very much for the link. So in my example, it is because numbers are immutable, in contrast to lists, right?

Comment: No. Mutable and immutable objects are treated identically for this.